# Adding Placeholder attributes base on input label with PURE JS - no jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, forms, placeholder

I need to get the label of each element and apply it to the input as a placeholder attribute, I get about half way though but cannot seem to get just the text of the element in order to add a attribute

Please note that i am not able to use jQuery in any regard

JS:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('p.form-field');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el, i){
  var chel = el.querySelectorAll('.field-label');
  console.log(chel.textContent);
});
```

HTML:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" action="nottelling" class="form" id="pardot-form">
    <p class="form-field first_name pd-text required ">
        <label class="field-label" for="25492_61334pi_25492_61334">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="25492_61334pi_25492_61334" id="25492_61334pi_25492_61334" value="" class="text" size="30" maxlength="32" onchange="" /> 
    </p>

    <div id="error_for_25492_61334pi_25492_61334" style="display:none"></div>

    <p class="form-field last_name pd-text required ">
        <label class="field-label" for="25492_61336pi_25492_61336">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="25492_61336pi_25492_61336" id="25492_61336pi_25492_61336" value="" class="text" size="30" maxlength="32" onchange="" /> 
    </p>

    <div id="error_for_25492_61336pi_25492_61336" style="display:none"></div>

    <p class="form-field email pd-text required ">
        <label class="field-label" for="25492_61338pi_25492_61338">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="25492_61338pi_25492_61338" id="25492_61338pi_25492_61338" value="" class="text" size="30" maxlength="255" onchange="piAjax.auditEmailField(this, 25492, 61338, 12545572);" /> 
    </p>

    <div id="error_for_25492_61338pi_25492_61338" style="display:none"></div>

    <p class="form-field company pd-text required ">
        <label class="field-label" for="25492_61340pi_25492_61340">Company</label>
        <input type="text" name="25492_61340pi_25492_61340" id="25492_61340pi_25492_61340" value="" class="text" size="30" maxlength="100" onchange="" /> 
    </p>

    <div id="error_for_25492_61340pi_25492_61340" style="display:none"></div>

    <p style="position:absolute; width:190px; left:-9999px; top: -9999px;visibility:hidden;">
        <label for="pi_extra_field">Comments</label>
        <input type="text" name="pi_extra_field" id="pi_extra_field" /> 
    </p>

    <input name="_utf8" type="hidden" value="&#9731;" />

    <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" accesskey="s" value="Send Message" /> 
    </p>

    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenDependentFields" id="hiddenDependentFields" value="" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var labels = document.querySelectorAll("label");
var i = labels.length;
while (i--) {
  var label = labels.item(i);
  var text = label.textContent;
  label.parentNode.classList.contains("required") && (text += "*");
  label.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("placeholder", text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks thats awesome!! One more question, how could i put in a conditional so if the p tag has a class of required then the placeholder has a * after the textContent? MUCH appreciated

Comment: New questions should be posted as new questions. An answer should be understandable and correct as an answer to the question asked, not to any tangential question asked in a comment. Doing otherwise confuses future visitors.

Comment: Note that this will bonk in earlier versions of IE if the label.parentNode.classList is empty. Suggest checking for nulls where appropriate to ensure compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

While the earlier answers work, I'd suggest a simpler approach, such as:

```
function placeholderLabels() {
  // get <input> elements that are in a <p> and follow a <label>:
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('p label + input');

  // iterate over those <input> elements:
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
  // input is the current <input> from the NodeList over which we're
  // iterating, here we set its placeholder property to either:
  // the textContent of the first <label> associated with the <input>
  // or to an empty string, if there's no associated <label>:
    input.placeholder = input.labels.length ? input.labels[0].textContent.trim() : '';
  });
}

placeholderLabels();
```

```js
function placeholderLabels() {
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('p label + input');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
    input.placeholder = input.labels.length ? input.labels[0].textContent.trim() : '';
  });
}

placeholderLabels();
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 7em;
}
p.required label::after {
  content: '*';
}
```

```html
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" action="nottelling" class="form" id="pardot-form">
  <p class="form-field first_name pd-text required ">
    <label class="field-label" for="25492_61334pi_25492_61334">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="25492_61334pi_25492_61334" id="25492_61334pi_25492_61334" value="" class="text" size="30" maxlength="32" onchange="" />
  </p>

  <div id="error_for_25492_61334pi_25492_61334" style="display:none"></div>

  <p class="form-field last_name pd-text required ">
    <label class="field-label" for="25492_61336pi_25492_61336">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="25492_61336pi_25492_61336" id="25492_61336pi_25492_61336" value="" class="text" size="30" maxlength="32" onchange="" />
  </p>

  <div id="error_for_25492_61336pi_25492_61336" style="display:none"></div>

  <p class="form-field email pd-text required ">
    <label class="field-label" for="25492_61338pi_25492_61338">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="25492_61338pi_25492_61338" id="25492_61338pi_25492_61338" value="" class="text" size="30" maxlength="255" onchange="piAjax.auditEmailField(this, 25492, 61338, 12545572);" />
  </p>

  <div id="error_for_25492_61338pi_25492_61338" style="display:none"></div>

  <p class="form-field company pd-text required ">
    <label class="field-label" for="25492_61340pi_25492_61340">Company</label>
    <input type="text" name="25492_61340pi_25492_61340" id="25492_61340pi_25492_61340" value="" class="text" size="30" maxlength="100" onchange="" />
  </p>

  <div id="error_for_25492_61340pi_25492_61340" style="display:none"></div>

  <p style="position:absolute; width:190px; left:-9999px; top: -9999px;visibility:hidden;">
    <label for="pi_extra_field">Comments</label>
    <input type="text" name="pi_extra_field" id="pi_extra_field" />
  </p>

  <input name="_utf8" type="hidden" value="&#9731;" />

  <p class="submit">
    <input type="submit" accesskey="s" value="Send Message" />
  </p>

  <input type="hidden" name="hiddenDependentFields" id="hiddenDependentFields" value="" />
</form>
```

It's worth reiterating at this point, however, that this is not a good user-interface; the placeholder should not replace the `<label>`, and if used should provide some guidance on what the `<input>` expects, such as the format or an expected value.

Answer (score 0):

You’re close: the problem is just that you are trying to use the object returned by the second `querySelectorAll` as if it were an element. It returns a collection, even when there is just one matching element. If you know that only one element matches it, simply index it with a zero. The same way you can access the `input` element, if you know there is only one such element inside each `p` element. So the essential code can be as follows:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('p.form-field');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el, i){
  el.querySelectorAll('input')[0].placeholder =
    el.querySelectorAll('.field-label')[0].textContent;
});
```

There are several possible approaches, depending on the assumptions you make about the source code.

Note: Duplicating label texts as placeholders is useless and disturbing. Replacing label text by placeholders is bad for accessibility and frowened upon in the HTML5 spec. But maybe the operation you are doing has some different purpose.

Comment: I know I know, explained to client but they want placeholdes :(